# An embedded expression cannot be used here

Tags: vb.net

In the body tag of an SMTP email sent to a user who has forgotten his password, I have the following in vb.net and Visual Studio 2013:

```
 Dim HtmlMessage As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("Hello" & <%= strEmailValue %> & ",<br /><br /> " & "To reset your password, please click on this <a style='color:#22BCES5' href=''>link.</a>", Nothing, "text/html" & "<br /><br />")
```

With regards to

```
<%= strEmailValue %>
```

I get the following error: 'An embedded expression cannot be used here'

strEmailValue is the email of the user who has forgotten his password. What would I replace my code with, please?

Comment: Why would you put `<%=  %>` around `strEmailValue`?

Comment: What exactly do you expect the final HTML to look like?

Comment: If this is in the code behind you don't need the <%= %> if the string you are passing to your function is only stremail.  If you your function is processing the <%= %>, then you need to pass it with quotes.

Comment: I was probably following Classic ASP when I did that as I was unsure what else to do. I was hoping the final result would be 'Hello, John@yajoo.com.....'. Very many thanks to the three of you. Much appreciated!